# Fail installing Streamlit in Professional Laptop

Tags: python, windows, streamlit

I am quite new using Python and Streamlit.
For a professional project, I need to use streamlit. The main problem is that in my personal laptop, I was able to install everything as it appears in the website (https://docs.streamlit.io/library/get-started/installation). The main problem is that in my professional laptop that it doesn't work.

When I apply the command "pip install streamlit" in my professional laptop, it appears this error:

"Collecting streamlit
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/streamlit/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/streamlit/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/streamlit/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/streamlit/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/streamlit/
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement streamlit (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for streamlit"

Could someone recommend me what should I do? Again I am so sorry if I am doing a stupid mistake, I am quite new and I don't have anyone to ask. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: By `professional`, do you mean the laptop provided by your corporation? Then it's likely behind a proxy or firewall which block you from access to pypi. You can try to visit pypi.org to confirm you can access the site first.

Comment: Yes, that it is what I mean with professional. I know there are a lot of restrictions, but I have access to pypi.org. Then I don't know what I should do.

Comment: Many corporations/enterprises use some kind of proxy server in their network....
If that applies to your corperation, you could try something like `pip install packageName --proxy proxy_Server:portnumber`, replacing `proxy_Server:portnumber` with the specifics of the proxy server